# What is this "1492E" reference number at the end of a magazine article?

Tags: citations, journalism, magazines

From the very end of an article in [*Essex Countryside* magazine, June 1978](https://boothiebarn.com/picture-galleries/booth-family/jbb-jr/article-about-junius-brutus-booth-iiis-murder-suicide-2/):

[image]

What is the name and purpose of that cryptic "1492E"?

I feel like I've seen this kind of thing somewhere before, but I'm blanking on its function (if I ever knew) or whether it has a name. My guess is that it might be related to reprints — like, if you called up the publisher a few years later and asked to get a copy of "article 1492E," they'd be able to find it faster than if all you knew was the article's title and date? But that's a wild guess.

The question behind the question is: is the "1492E" relevant in some way when citing this article in a bibliography?

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! Interesting question. Is there a specific citation style that you have to follow?

Comment: "Is there a specific citation style that you have to follow?" — Well, my immediate use-case is just a `{{cite newspaper` on Wikipedia. But *assuming* this "1492E" is some kind of unambiguous reference number — which it might not be at all! — then I'd be interested to know about *any* citation styles, or pretty much any other *contexts*, in which it might be relevant or important.

Comment: https://i2.wp.com/greydogtales.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/whhessex3.jpg   This is another example of such reference number from another article from 1977. Notice that the reference number has increased.

Answer (score 1):

**Meaning of number**

The magazine is called *[Essex Life](https://www.essexlifemag.co.uk/)* today. They have a website and contact form. If you'd like to learn what the number meant you could contact them and ask.

**Citing the article**

But that number is irrelevant if what you want to do is cite that article. None of the conventions I know – APA, MLA, Chicago, etc. – mention a "number at the end of an article" as part of what you need to provide.

**Explanation**

Citations contain information that allows you to identify and access the cited text. Now, if you found a citation with that number in it, you wouldn't know what it meant and it wouldn't help you to find the source. Therefore, that number is not only unnecessary in a citation, it would in fact be confusing and thereby undermine the purpose of the citation.

Comment: Why don't *you* contact them and ask what the numbers meant? I don't see how this really answers the question.

Comment: @F1Krazy First of all, the "question behind the question", as stated in the question body, is: "is the '1492E' relevant in some way when citing this article in a bibliography?" I answered that question. No, it is not relevant. Because, as I stated, a number at the end of an article is not part of any citation convention (APA, MLA, Chicago etc.). I hope you don't expect me to expound all the conventions for which thick handbooks have been written in a Stack Exchange answer to prove that none of them mention such a number. [contd.]

Comment: [contd.] Second, I made an effort and did the research to find out the current name of the magazine to provide the asker an opportunity to satisfy their curiosity. I think that's commendable and not cause for a downvote. I chose to post that information here because an answer to my inquiry would take days, and I felt the asker would get a quicker reply by directly inquiring themselves. Also, I'm not curious to learn the meaning of the number myself, because, as I already said, it is irrelevant to the intent of this question.

Comment: I thought the answer was fine.  Normally a "contact them" response isn't very helpful but here the poster is saying it's specific to the magazine and not relevant in any other context.

Comment: _If you'd like to learn what the number meant you could contact them and ask._ — Yes, I would like to know that. — Unfortunately, the editor of "Essex Life" replies: _Sorry, I can’t help you there, and I’m afraid there is no one still at the business who has been here longer than I have. Sorry to not be of assistance this time._ — So the question is still open.